# How can I use templated generic constraints in C++/CLI

Tags: templates, generics, c++-cli, constraints

I'm having some trouble figuring out if I can use templated generic constraints in C++/CLI. here's an example

```
template<typename T>
public ref class wrapped 
{
public:
    T* t;

    T doTthing(){return *t;}
};
```

Here's a simple templated managed class, wrapping an unmanaged type T. I can use this class as a constraint for a generic

```
// works
generic<class genclass> where genclass : wrapped<int>
public ref class testclass3
{
public:
    genclass gc;

    int test()
    {
        return gc->doTthing();
    }
};
```

This works fine. What I can't figure out is how to preserve both the templating and the generic, i.e.

```
//Does Not Work!
template<typename T>
generic<class genclass>  where genclass : wrapped<T>
public ref class testclass4
{
public:
    genclass gc;

    T test()
    {
        return gc->doTthing();
    }
};
```

Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix templates with generics in the same declaration.

The class should either be templated or generic. See: [**Managed Templates**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177213.aspx)

Templates are mush more expressive, so i would suggest you use them instead.

If you want to simulate a constraint (same technique would work in c++ by the way..) you could do:

```
template<class T, class GENCLASS>
public ref class testclass4
{
private:
    typedef typename GENCLASS::wrapped<T> Constraint1;
public:
    genclass gc;

    T test()
    {
        return gc->doTthing();
    }
};
```

If the class does not inherit from `wrapped<T>` then the `typedef` declaration will fail saying that "wrapped is not a member of GENCLASS".